# client id for google signin get error custom scheme URIs are not allowed for "WEB" client type

Tags: react-native, expo, google-authentication

I created client id to test it in expo app which apis is written in nodejs like these steps

```
Application Type: Android Application
Package name: match with the value of android.package in app.json.
Authorized JavaScript origins
URIs:http://localhost:3000
Authorized redirect URIs
http://localhost:3000/googleLogin
```

and use it in my code

```
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';

export default function Signup() {
    const googleSignin = async() => {
        let result = await Google.logInAsync({
            androidClientId: `${CLIENT_ID}`
          });
          console.log(result)
      }
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>googleSignin()}>     
     <Text>LOG IN WITH GOOGLE</Text>
</TouchableOpacity >
)
}
```

I get that error >> Authorization error Error 400: invalid_request  custom scheme URIs are not allowed for "WEB" client type

Comment: Try using local IP address. So http://localhost:3000 to http://192.168.1.5:3000, to note that 5 in http://192... is your local machine number

Comment: not accepted on the field I got that error 
Invalid Origin: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).